# Buscar archivo en una carpeta en Java

Tags: java, recursión

Estoy realizando la busqueda de un archivo llamado "miArchivo.java" contenido en una carpeta donde hay mas carpetas por ejemplo:

[image: Directorio en el que empiezo mi busqueda de el archillo llamado "miArchivo.java"]

[image]

[image]

Aqui el codigo que he realizado, habia pensado en un llamado recursivo (Envio como parametro file como directorio y el nombre del archivo como String)

```
 private static void buscarArchivo(String fichero, File directorioFile) {


    //Primero que todo listo mis ficheros utilizando .listFiles
    //este método devuelve todos los ficheros asociados al directorio en un array de Files.
    File[] lista = directorioFile.listFiles();

    if (lista != null) {
        for (File elemento : lista) {
            if (elemento.isDirectory()) { //.isDirectory comprueba si el fichero instanciado en una clase File es un directorio o no
                                          //Anteriormente solo comprobamos que si existia el directorio pero no el archivo.
                buscarArchivo(fichero, elemento);

            } else if (fichero.equalsIgnoreCase(elemento.getName())) {
                //buscarArchivo(fichero, elemento);
                System.out.println("Archivo encontrado con exito! ");
                System.out.println (elemento.getParentFile());
                System.out.println(elemento.getName());
                System.out.println("\n-----------------------------");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Al momento de llamar el metodo en el main solo indica que la ruta si existe mas no se ejecuta, que hago mal ¿?

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

    String fichero = "MiArchivo.java";
    //Lo primero que hay que hacer es crear un objeto de tipo File con el nombre del directorio a listar.
    File directorioFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Ruta");

    //Comprueblo que el directorio existe con un metodo que se llama .(exist) que hace parte de la clase File de java

    if (directorioFile.exists()){
    System.out.println("El directorio existe, procediendo a buscar el fichero...");

    
    //Primero listo todos los archivos de la carpeta 
    

    buscarArchivo(fichero, directorioFile);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("El directorio no existe, verifique la ruta...");
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tu método no está tan lejos de funcionar. Te faltan tres cosas (detalladas más abajo)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buscar("Lombok.java", Paths.get(".").toFile()));
}

private static File buscar(String archivoABuscar, File directorio) {
    File[] archivos = directorio.listFiles();
    for (File archivo : archivos) {
        if (archivo.getName().equals(archivoABuscar)) {
            return archivo;
        }
        if (archivo.isDirectory()) {
            File resultadoRecursion = buscar(archivoABuscar, archivo);
            if (resultadoRecursion != null) {
                return resultadoRecursion;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

1. Cuando encontrás el archivo lo tenés que retornar.
2. Cuando terminás    de recorrer la lista tenés que retornar null.
3. Cuando encontrás un directorio tenés que hacer la llamada recursiva, y si ésta retorna distinto de null retornar con ese valor (ya que alguna llamada interna de la recursión encontró el archivos), caso contrario no hacer nada para seguir inspeccionando la lista.

Comment: Amigo ya he actualizado el codigo pero ahora presento otro inconveniente..., podrias ayudarme ¿? Dejo hilo...   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392380/porque-no-sirve-mi-metodo-recursivo?noredirect=1#comment702747_392380

Comment: El método que tenés en la otra pregunta que me pasás está muy mal y no va a funcionar. El que habías escrito acá estaba mejor. Y simplemente con las indicaciones que te dí te va a funcionar.

Comment: Lo se amigo, pero hay un problema en mi clase se me pidio como recursivo y no puedo hacer uso de For, iterator, etc., a menos que sea por llamado recursivo, De igual forma te agradezco por la reespuesta.

Comment: Que sea recursivo no implica que no pueda tener un bucle dentro. El `for` está para iterar los archivos/directorios que contiene un directorio determinado. Y la recursión ocurre cada vez que aparece un nuevo directorio.

Answer (score 3):

NOTA: Cuando las cosas no salen, es importante:

1. Depurar el programa y comprobar la ejecución paso a paso, que salgan los valores que esperamos. Y cuando no salen, investigar porqué.
2. Leer la documentación de los métodos usados.

Solución:

[Javadoc de *java.io.File#listFiles()*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()); énfasis mío:

> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the **files** in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.

*listFiles()* solo te devuelve los ficheros, no los directorios. Para que te devuelva todo, puedes usar *java.io.File#list()* que devuelve tanto ficheros como directorios.

Si (por ejemplo) hubieras imprimido la lista de elementos obtenidos por *listFiles*, habrías visto que no salían los directorio y hubieras podido ir tirando del hilo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!