# ¿Porque no sirve mi metodo recursivo?

Tags: java, recursión

Estoy realizando un metodo recursivo que realiza la busqueda de un archivo llamado "miArchivo.java" contenido en una carpeta donde hay mas carpetas.

```
private static void buscarArchivo(String fichero, File directorioFile, int pos) throws IOException {


    //Primero que todo listo mis ficheros utilizando .listFiles
    //este método devuelve todos los ficheros asociados al directorio en un array de Files.
    File[] lista = directorioFile.listFiles();

    if (lista != null) {//Por si no hay archivos en la ruta uno nunca sabe
        if(pos < lista.length){//Recorro mi lista de "Files" algunos son directorios de carpetas y otros archivos contenidos
                                          //en dichos directorios

                File archivoAuxiliar= lista[pos]; //Creo un objeto de tipo File para guardar ahi lo que sera bien un diretorio o archivo

                if (archivoAuxiliar.isDirectory()) {//Verifico que sea una ruta o archivo
                    //System.out.println(archivoAuxiliar.getName());
                    buscarArchivo(fichero, lista[pos+1],pos);//Si es verdadero llamo el metodo nuevamente enviando la siguiento posicion de la lista
                                                     //que vendria siendo otra carpeta con mas carpetas y archivos en esta.
                }else{//Si es un archivo los compara hasta encontrar el que buscamos

                    if(fichero.equals(archivoAuxiliar.getName())==true){
                        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Archivo encontrado con exito!   "+archivoAuxiliar.getName()+"\n En la ruta: "+archivoAuxiliar.getParentFile());
                        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------");
                    }

                }
           }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ups.. No hay archivos en la ruta!");
        }
    }
```

Quizas esten mal ubicados los return o falten returns?, puse un par de Sysos entre las iteraciones de las posiciones para ver si entraba correctamente y si accede a la carpeta en donde esta el archivo mas no retorna que si la encontro y en donde, ¿Que hago mal?

Aqui el main por si deseas ayudarme y lo ocupas:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    String fichero = "MiArchivo.java.txt"; //No eliminar el .txt ya que windows por lo menos en mi caso lo detecta como .txt siendo.java


    //Lo primero que hay que hacer es crear un objeto de tipo File con el nombre del directorio a listar.


    File directorioFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Ruta...");
    //Cambiar de acuerdo a la ruta que valla a buscar en su pc


    //Compruebo que el directorio existe con un metodo que se llama .isDirectory que hace parte de la clase File de java

    if (directorioFile.isDirectory()){//.isDirectory comprueba si el fichero instanciado en una clase File es un directorio o no
    System.out.println("El directorio existe, procediendo a buscar el fichero...");
    System.out.println("\n");

    buscarArchivo(fichero, directorioFile,0);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("El directorio no existe, verifique la ruta...");
    }




}
```

Comment: No estás iterando el arreglo porque usas un `if` en vez de un bucle. Aquí está el problema: `if(pos < lista.length)`

Comment: Pero si vuelvo a llamar mi metodo recursivo con lista[pos+1] no tendria que avanzar de posicion para iterar ¿? o mas bien tendria que ser pos+1 pero creo que daria igual...

Comment: No iterarías la lista, simplemente estarías entrando (en el mejor de los casos) por una sola rama de la estructura de directorios. En el momento que encuentre un archivo en lugar de un directorio se detendría el método, sea este el archivo buscado o no.

Comment: Entiendo muchas gracias, alguna idea de como arreglar el problema sin tener que modificar mi iterador como if ¿? ya que se me pidio recursivamente y no puedo hacer uso de for, iterator, etc.

Comment: te recomiendo aprender programacion dinamica , para hacer mejores soluciones y optimas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentaba el problema que estás teniendo es no estás iterando todo el contenido del directorio actual de antes realizar una búsqueda recursiva en sus sub-directorios.

Aquí está el problema

```
if (pos < lista.length)
```

Luego haces esto esperando iterar el contenido del directorio actual con una llamada recursiva al método

```
buscarArchivo(fichero, lista[pos+1], pos)
```

Esto tienen muchos errores puesto que a lo sumo estarías haciendo una búsqueda en profundidad a través de una sola rama de la estructura de directorios. Pero en el momento que lo que encuentre sea un archivo el método finalizará, siendo este el buscado o no, aunque queden archivos y directorios por consultar.

Lo que haría yo es: itero sobre todo el contenido del directorio para buscar el archivo. Si el elemento analizado es un archivo y su nombre conincide con el buscado lo devuelvo. Si es un directorio entonces aplico sobre este el mismo proceso de búsqueda recursivamente.

Sería algo como esto:

```
private static File buscarArchivo(String nombreFichero, File directorioFile) throws IOException {
        
    File[] lista = directorioFile.listFiles();

    if (lista == null || lista.lenght == 0) {
        // Si el directorio está vacío devuelvo null porque no lo encontré
        return null;
    }
    
    // Itero el contenido del directorio para buscar el archivo en este
    for (File f : lista) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            // Si f es un directorio busco recursivamente dentro de él
            File archivoEncontrado = buscarArchivo(nombreFichero, f);
            // Si encontró el archivo lo devuelvo, sino continúo con la iteración
            if (archivoEncontrado != null) {
                return archivoEncontrado;
            }
        } else if (f.getName().equals(nombreFichero)) {// Si f es un archivo compruebo si es el buscado
            // Si lo encontré lo devuelvo, sino continúo con la iteración
            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

Este método devolverá una instancia de `File` que representa el archivo encontrado, o `null` si no se encuentra el archivo.

Ten en cuenta que aunque apliques una iteración para examinar el contenido del directorio actual, el proceso de búsqueda es recursivo porque el método `buscarArchivo()` se llama a sí mismo una y otra vez.